# How can I harness `apply/lapply/sapply` instead of a `for` loop to improve performance?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I would like to speed-up the below function (`fndf`) which calls another function (`fn1`) based on a character array.

`fndf`- New Function
`list_s` - character array - `chr [1:400]`
`rdata_i` - empty data frame (for initialization)
`fn1` - another custom function
`rdata2` - data frame with `3000 obs of 40 variables`
`mdata` -  data.frame
`nm` - character

```
   fndf = function(list_s, rdata2){
                rdata_i = df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                         File=character(), 
                         User=character(), 
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                for(i in 1:length(list_s))
                {
                    rdata = fn1(list_s[i], rdata2)
                    rdata_i = rbind(rdata, rdata_i)
                }
                return(unique(rdata_i))
           }
```

Can we also improve performance of the `function` below?

```
    fn1 = function(nm, mdata){
                 n0 = mdata[mdata$Sign==nm,]
                 cn0 = unique(c(n0$Name))
                 repeat{
                      n1c = mdata[mdata$Mgr %in% cn0,]
                      n0 = unique(rbind(n0,n1c))
                      if(nrow(n1c)==0){
                                return(n0)
                                break
                                 } 
                      cn0= unique(c(n1c$Name))
                      }
                }
```

Comment: your slowdown is probably due to `rdata_i = rbind(rdata, rdata_i)`; it's generally bad practice to grow objects in a for loop (too much copying and moving data around). Check out the "R Inferno" book, it's got some advice on this.

Comment: try this, `ld = lapply(list_s, fn1, rdata2); do.call(rbind, ld)`

Comment: You need to make your question reproducible. Possibly, you don't even need a loop.

Comment: How is this question related to recursion?

Comment: `ldply` - 46 seconds, `lapply` - 45 seconds, `for` - 30 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s indeed hard to say how to best transform your loop into an `*apply` statement, and even harder to say whether this will speed it up. But fundamentally, the following transformation is what you’re after, and it definitely makes the function simpler and more readable. It also quite possibly corresponds to a substantial performance gain due to the loss of the repeated `rbind`, as noted by baptiste:

```
fndf = function (list_s, rdata2)
    as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, unique(lapply(list_s, fn1, rdata2))))
```

(Yes. That’s a single statement.)

Also note that I’m now applying the `unique` directly to the list rather than the `data.frame`. This changes the semantics – `unique` is specialised for `data.frame`s – but is probably the right thing for your purposes, and it will be more efficient because it means that we don’t construct a needlessly big `data.frame` with redundant rows.

Comment: This reduced the time to 15 seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without your data/functions, but here is a solution with `plyr` and some placeholder data:

```
list_s<-LETTERS
rdata2<-data.frame(a=rep(LETTERS,2),b=runif(52),c=runif(52)*10)
fn1<-function(a,b=rdata2)b[rdata2$a==a,]
fn1("A")

require(plyr) # for ldply function, which takes a list and returns a dataframe
result<-ldply(1:length(list_s),function(x)fn1(list_s[x],rdata2))
head(result)

  a           b         c
1 A 0.281940237 2.7774933
2 A 0.023611392 0.6067029
3 B 0.456547803 9.4219258
4 B 0.645783746 5.3094864
5 C 0.475949523 4.8580622
6 C 0.006063407 2.5851738
```